# Windows 10 Explorer displays wrong values for total size and free space for WebDAV drive

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am developing a WebDAV connection for a database based ECM system using the IT HIT WebDAV engine and .net 5.

I have mapped WebDAV to a network drive in explorer.

When I list all drives in explorer, the total size and free space of the WebDAV drive incorrectly shows the same values as the C drive.

The responses that the WebDAV server sends back to explorer (Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.19042) do not contain any information about total size or free space at all, as far as I have seen.
Is it possible to send this data in the WebDAV response (are there any special properties for this)?
Or is it possible to make the explorer show, if not the correct values, then rather no values at all?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same behavior with any WebDAV server including the one from IT Hit. The drive mounting on Windows is using the Microsoft Mini-redirector driver to mount the WebDAV file system. This driver always shows the size identical to the drive C:. Unfortunately, it does not request the available and free space from the server, even though the server properly reports the free and used space.

I guess one of the reasons for this behavior is that mini-redirector caches file content on the system drive and is probably limited by system drive size.